# To use spinner to select node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a spinner with option customer and driver in my signup page
and this is my code

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ActivitySignUpBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    private Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
        progressdialog.setMessage("pls wait while we create your account");
        binding.SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressdialog.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString()
                        ,binding.Password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressdialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Users user=new Users(binding.Username.getText().toString(),binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Account created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                                    database.getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(id).setValue(user);
                            
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

I wanted to know how to access the variable text from 2nd last overide to the part where i am adding the values to nodes
the part where i wrote

```
database.getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(id).setValue(user);
```

i actually want to put it in if-else clause so tht if the option selected in spinner is not driver
then it goes to .child("customer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code. You can get directly spinner selected value inside override method

```
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressdialog.dismiss();
   //Here you can get selected item from spinner
    String selectedOption  =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    Users user=new Users(binding.Username.getText().toString(),binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Password.getText().toString());
    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Account created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String id=task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
    database.getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(id).setValue(user);
    }
    else {
      Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
   });
```